# IBM Watson Speech to Text not working in built app

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working in a project in Unity 3D that uses the Speech to Text service. It's quite simple and works fine in the Unity editor, but when I build the project it doesn't listen.

I'm working with a MacBook Pro and I export it to the same OS. I thought that it could be any problem in the rest of my code, or a corrupted project issue, so I have created a new empty project and I've followed the steps indicated in: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk 
When I open the scene Assets/Watson/Examples/ExampleStreaming it recognizes the speech in Unity, but when I export it the results are the same, it doesn't listen. I've checked the file permissions and I have added read and write for all users. Also I have entered in sound preferences in my OS and everything seems to be ok.

I've looked in the player logs (home/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log) and it contains:

> ```
> Setting up 2 worker threads for Enlighten.
>   Thread -> id: 70000bd59000 -> priority: 1 
>   Thread -> id: 70000bddc000 -> priority: 1 
> debugger-agent: Unable to listen on 6
> ##utp:{"type":"MemoryLeaks","version":2,"phase":"Immediate","time":1562101403605,"processId":465,"allocatedMemory":115452,"memoryLabels":[{"Default":1560},{"NewDelete":102552},{"Manager":256},{"GfxDevice":8656},{"Physics":32},{"Serialization":40},{"Terrain":88},{"String":1468},{"DynamicArray":72},{"PoolAlloc":-88},{"VR":536},{"SceneManager":280}]}
> ```

Comment: What platform are you publishing to?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it. I tried to export it to Windows (which worked fine) and to Web Player but it gave me an error when installing the library, so I decided to upgrade Unity to 2019.2.2f1 version. It didn't work either because it seems that the Unity Watson lib is not compatible with Web Player, but the thing is that when I tried to export it to Mac again suddenly it worked fine. The built app now ask for permissions for using the microphone, so if I accept, it listens and converts it to text perfectly. So, at the end, I don't know exactly what made it work, if it was the version upgrade, or the compilation for other platforms, which forced to rebuild everything.

Comment: The IBM Watson SDK for Unity does not support Unity Web Player.
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#configuring-unity